# Sorting rows in csv file using Python Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a quick question regarding sorting rows in a csv files using Pandas. The csv file which I have has the data that looks like:

```
quarter week    Value
  5       1      200   
  3       2      100
  2       1       50
  2       2      125
  4       2      175 
  2       3      195 
  3       1      10
  5       2      190
```

I need to sort in following way: sort the quarter and the corresponding weeks. So the output should look like following:

```
quarter week    Value
  2       1      50  
  2       2      125
  2       3      195
  3       1      10
  3       2      100    
  4       2      175
  5       1      200
  5       2      190
```

My attempt:

```
df = df.sort('quarter', 'week')
```

But this does not produce the correct result. Any help/suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note**: `sort` has been deprecated in favour of [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values), which you should use in Pandas 0.17+.

Typing `help(df.sort)` gives:

```
sort(self, columns=None, column=None, axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False) method of pandas.core.frame.DataFrame instance
    Sort DataFrame either by labels (along either axis) or by the values in
    column(s)

    Parameters
    ----------
    columns : object
        Column name(s) in frame. Accepts a column name or a list or tuple
        for a nested sort.

[...]

Examples
--------
>>> result = df.sort(['A', 'B'], ascending=[1, 0])

[...]
```

and so you pass the columns you want to sort as a list:

```
>>> df
   quarter  week  Value
0        5     1    200
1        3     2    100
2        2     1     50
3        2     2    125
4        4     2    175
5        2     3    195
6        3     1     10
7        5     2    190
>>> df.sort(["quarter", "week"])
   quarter  week  Value
2        2     1     50
3        2     2    125
5        2     3    195
6        3     1     10
1        3     2    100
4        4     2    175
0        5     1    200
7        5     2    190
```

Comment: I know this answer was given four years ago, but thought I would add that `df.sort(['A', 'B'])` is now deprecated.  The new method is `df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B'])`.

Answer (score 9):

New answer, as of 14 March 2019

```
df.sort_values(by=["COLUMN"], ascending=False)
```

This returns a new sorted data frame, doesn't update the original one.

Note: You can change the ascending parameter according to your needs, without passing it, it will default to `ascending=True`

Comment: doesnt help me, on CSV it says: 102.314 little than 106, how can it be possible?

Answer (score -1):

`DataFrame` object has no attribute `sort`

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but this answer could be greatly improved! You have just stated the reason why that method does not work, but didn't provide an actual solution for the problem. Please be a bit more verbose and try to answer the original question! (Also, posting a short answer to an old question which already has a solution is not usually useful.)